# How to add existing nodes to a book page in drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

This is my scenario: I have several nodes of different content types in my drupal site. I want to create a book page and add these existing contents to book page as child pages rather then creating child pages.

Already looked at outline designer and bookmadesimple module, but i think none of these modules has this functionality. Is there any module available for that or i need to build a custom module?

edit:
let me give an example:
I have 4 existing nodes (content):

```
content 1
content 2
content 3
content 4
```

I have a book named Issue 1, I want to know that
is there any way to add my existing contents to book "Issue 1" so that it shows like below:

```
Issue1
     ->content 1
     ->content 2
     ->content 3
     ->content 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add node reference type field in your book content type and reference those other content types. You can make that field to be "multiple" so you would be able to select unlimited number of those nodes. So inside your book content type template you'll get referenced nodes as an array and you can iterate trough it.

Other (opposite) option would be to have that node reference filed in those other content type for referencing specific book. In that case you'll need help of view's module to collect all nodes that are referencing same book.

Comment: I will try that and will let u know the outcome..thanks :)

Comment: I have checked that option, it will add nodes as reference to a book page. But I want the nodes as book page. Let me give an example:

I have 4 existing nodes (content):
content 1
content 2
content 3
content 4

I have a book named Issue 1
is there any way to add my existing contents to book "Issue 1" so that it shows like below:

Issue1
     ->content 1
     ->content 2
     ->content 3
     ->content 4

Comment: How it will be shown is decided in you template files. You will have all the values entered in back-end available and you can display then as you wish.